# How can I find out when an Editor intends to publish my paper?

Tags: publications

My manuscript was accepted in an ISI journal 6 months ago, but it is not published online yet. I found that the journal published online some manuscripts that were accepted after my acceptance date. Therefore, I sent several emails to the journal Editor but, I did not receive any answer.

How can I find when the journal aim to publish my manuscript?

Comment: Are you comfortable saying what journal it is? I am curious. Also, some journals will accept papers and have them on a back "backlog". They will publish the backlog journals when they feel like they don't have any newer and more "worthy" articles to publish.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, a publisher uses an online system that allows authors to track the status of their paper. Double-check your inbox (particularly Spam folder) for a automatic email from such system (search the journal name for example).

If you are sure that you did not hear from the publisher and the journal editor within 6 months, I would say, it becomes worrying. The academic publishing was never a particularly fast process, but this situation probably oversteps the limits. Consider writing to the support team of your publisher and to Editor-in-Chief of your journal with inquiry. Also, consider sharing the name of the journal with your peers to prevent future misuse of anyone's precious time.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, to tell the truth, I am worrying why they keep my manuscript, but I have no other choice except waiting.I tried to find the Associate Editor Email, however I was not successful....

Comment: With publication in dead-tree format, journals occasionally shoot themselves in the foot by accepting more papers than they can publish in a single issue (and if the editor is not serious about it, this problem can snowball very quickly). Online publication is a totally different game, as your paper can be made downloadable the moment you submit the corrected proofs. As Dmitry said, six months is way way excessive. Keep pestering the editor and consider threatening the journal with a retraction if they don't take action soon.